# angularjs - bind ng-click for dynamically loaded DOM from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a ng controller PostsListController to control the `ng-click` for the loaded images

```
  <div ng-controller='PostsListController'>
   <ul id="wookmark_container">
    <% @posts.each do |post|%>
     <li>
        <a href='#' ng-click="open()"> <img src="image_path" ></a>
     </li>
     <%end%>
   </ul>
  </div>


angular.module('myapp')
  .controller('PostsListController',  function($scope, $http){

    $scope.open = function(postId){
    };
  };

});


  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($) {
      var container = '#wookmark_container',
      $container = $(container),
      tileCount = 30,
      $window = $(window),
      $document = $(document),
      wookmark;

  // Initialize Wookmark
  wookmark = new Wookmark(container, {
    offset: 5, // Optional, the distance between grid items
    outerOffset: 10, // Optional, the distance to the containers border
    itemWidth: 260 // Optional, the width of a grid item
  });

      function onScroll() {

        var winHeight = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : $window.height(), // iphone fix
            closeToBottom = ($window.scrollTop() + winHeight > $document.height() - 100);
        if (closeToBottom) {

          var $items = $('li', $container),
              $firstTen = $items.slice(0, 10).clone().css('opacity', 0);
          $container.append($firstTen);
          wookmark.initItems();
          wookmark.layout(true, function () {
            // Fade in items after layout
            setTimeout(function() {
              $firstTen.css('opacity', 1);
            }, 300);
          });
        }
      };
      // Capture scroll event.
      $window.bind('scroll.wookmark', onScroll);
    })(jQuery);
  </script>
```

**updated scripts**

html part added `scroll`

`<ul scroll id="wookmark_container" style="position: relative">`

```
  angular.module('bidwars').directive("scroll", function ($window) {
      return function(scope, element, attrs) {
          angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
              scope.$apply(function(){
                  // write your jquery logic here

                  var container = '#wookmark_container',
                      $container = $(container),
                      tileCount = 30,
                      $window = $(window),
                      $document = $(document),
                      wookmark;

                  // Initialize Wookmark
                  wookmark = new Wookmark(container, {
                    offset: 5, // Optional, the distance between grid items
                    outerOffset: 10, // Optional, the distance to the containers border
                    itemWidth: 260 // Optional, the width of a grid item
                  });

                  var winHeight = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : $window.height(), // iphone fix
                      closeToBottom = ($window.scrollTop() + winHeight > $document.height() - 100);
                  if (closeToBottom) {
                    // Get the first then items from the grid, clone them, and add them to the bottom of the grid
                    var $items = $('li', $container),
                        $firstTen = $items.slice(0, 10).clone().css('opacity', 0);
                    $container.append($firstTen);
                    wookmark.initItems();
                    wookmark.layout(true, function () {
                      // Fade in items after layout
                      setTimeout(function() {
                        $firstTen.css('opacity', 1);
                      }, 300);
                    });
                  }
              });
          });
      };
  });



    (function ($) {
      var container = '#wookmark_container',
          $container = $(container),
          tileCount = 30,
          $window = $(window),
          $document = $(document),
          wookmark;

      // Initialize Wookmark
      wookmark = new Wookmark(container, {
        offset: 5, // Optional, the distance between grid items
        outerOffset: 10, // Optional, the distance to the containers border
        itemWidth: 260 // Optional, the width of a grid item
      });

    })(jQuery);
```

It works fine for all images loaded at initial page loading. But when I load more images using jquery to `wookmark_container` . The `ng-click` not working for new loaded images from jquery. My guess is that the ng-controller not aware of these new loaded image from jquery.

How do I let ng-controller now these new loaded ones from jquery? How to make  dynamically loaded images' `ng-click` event work?

Comment: Angular doesn't know about the new elements. I suggest to follow @Sam's advice and do everything in Angular.

Comment: @zeroflagL  Please see my updated scripts. Somehow it still not triggering `ng-click` for new loaded `li` items

Comment: Because you still don't do everything with Angular. Hardly anything, to be honest. Ideally you would use [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) for your list.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, wrap your update code in `$apply`, like so -

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
        // update your html by jQuery
    });
```

This will make sure AngularJS engine knows of any changes to DOM.

Read [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-$scope.$apply()) for more detail.

You can do something like this -

```
app.directive("scroll", function ($window) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
            $scope.$apply(function(){
                // write your jquery logic here
            });
        });
    };
});
```

Haven't tried this with your code, but should work.

Comment: I have updated the `ng-controller` code and jquery code. Do you think it is possible to wrap the jquery to angularjs?

Comment: $apply is specifically used for that purpose - running code from outside angular bounds.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please give a bit hint how to apply outside angular( in jquery) ? I a totally new to angulars

Comment: Ideally you would create a directive in your controller and bind it to your DOM element, and put your jQuery there. But the way your jQuery code is, it will be difficult and kinda mess up angular for you. I would suggest you convert this code to pure angular.

Comment: Updated my answer to give some idea for your case.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have updated the original post. I haven't tried yet. `app.directive` should handle the scroll event,. How about the initialization part of  `wookmark` should go? IN jquery or angulars?

Comment: I would say if you are doing things in angular, do it the angular way. Touch jQuery only when it is really necessary. You can do anything in angular, just will need to think a little differently.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74371/discussion-between-icn-and-sam).

Comment: Cool :) I have added the directive in javascript. It seems not catching scroll event? Do I need to add something in html as well?

Comment: Yes, you do :) I would suggest first read up on directives from angularjs page. Then try and let me know what is not working.

Comment: Thanks :). I have updated op .I have made scroll events event working. Now when scroll it loads new items. But for new loaded items `ng-click` still not working

Comment: Ok, can you create a codepen or plnkr of what you have now so we can work on that.